# hover over large bars in R shiny plot

Tags: r, hover, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny project, I'm plotting a lot of data, and in order to understand where dose each bar in the plot come from, I'm using a hovering.

When I hover over a bar, I'm getting the row in data frame that it refers to, using the `nearPoints()` function. (from the `shiny` package)

If the bars are small I have no problem. but if I have large enough bars, or if I zoom in, I need to hover over the beggining of the bar, is there a way to get the row when I'm hover over any part of the bar?
thanks!

```
# reproducible example
# when hovering over the small segments/bars there's no problem
# hovering over the long/short, you need to go to the beggining
# of the segment/bar in order to see the hovering info
library(shiny)
library(stats)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")),
  fluidRow(plotOutput("myplot", hover = hoverOpts(id ="myplot_hover")))
))

id <- c(rep("mut1 vs wt", 100), "long", "short")
s <- c(seq(10, 1000, length.out = 100), 30, 90)
e <- c(seq(15, 1005, length.out = 100), 900, 210)
log <- c(rnorm(100), -3, 2)
df <- data.frame(id,s,e,log)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "start","end","log2")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df) + facet_grid(id~.) + 
      geom_segment(data=subset(df, grepl("wt",df$id)),
                   mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,log2>0,color=log2>0)) +
      geom_segment(data=subset(df,grepl("short$",id)),
                   mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0)) +
      geom_segment(data=subset(df,grepl("long$",id)),
                   mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2,size=3,color=log2>0)) #+
  })
  output$hover_info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(df, input$myplot_hover,maxpoints=1)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you please provide reproducible example

Comment: working on something

Comment: I edited my question and added an example.
thanks for your comment :)

Comment: anyone? I'm stuck here..